# Remove decimals in google chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to remove the decimals in google chart tooltip. I want it to round to the nearest integer. 
[image: This is what I got now]

Here is my google chart code. I guess i haft to put something more in my options if this is possible? I don't want to tweak my data that's go in to the chart. So it should just happen when it is present in the diagram.

```
  var drawChart = function (data, type, firstIsAverage, vAxisHeader) {
    var shift = (firstIsAverage === true) ? 0 : 1;

    var fontname = 'Roboto';
    var fontsize = 14;

    var chartObject = {
        type: type,
        display: false,
        data: data,
        options: {
            chartArea: {
                left: 100, 
                top: 30,
                width: 800,
                height: 240
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: vAxisHeader,
                titleTextStyle: {
                    italic: false
                }
            },
            fontName: fontname,
            fontSize: fontsize,
            legend: 'none',
            colors: colors.slice(shift),
            isStacked: "true",
            fill: 20,
            displayExactValues: false,
        },
        formatters: {}
    };
    setAllColumnsVisible(chartObject);

    return chartObject;
};
```

Comment: You should look at the documentation for [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#numberformat)

Comment: I'm sorry but cant make it work. Should `fractionDigits`go in to the option?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try this 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johanbyren/9qc71ksr/)

Comment: @WhiteHat's answer below is good. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAxtmann/nf5d9kma/)

Comment: I have some problem. In my `formatter.format(data, i);` i get an error: `TypeError: a.L` is not a function. Do you guys have any clue what that is?
I never include `google.visualization` so maybe that´s why. So I can´t use the `data.getNumberOfColumns()` either. 
But you guy are awesome and I can se that the solution I got from @Whitehat works in the fiddle. So should I make he's answer green even its not working on my personal stuff?

Comment: why don't you include `google.visualization`? how you can you have a chart without it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#numberformat) as in this example, and pointed out in the comments

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours', 'Other'],
    ['Work',     7007.08, 7427.41],
    ['Eat',      8227.88, 6427.80],
    ['Commute',  9447.48, 9427.23],
    ['Watch TV', 6667.28, 6427.66],
    ['Sleep',    7887.18, 7427.79]
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,##0'});

  // format number columns
  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    formatter.format(data, i);
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: This will do it. Here's a fiddle I was working on. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johanbyren/9qc71ksr/)